# MYSQL insert from one table to another but gets error: subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MYSQL database (`cssp_release_info,det_release_info`) and I want to copy some records from `cssp_release_info` to `det_release_info` and the below is my query.

```
    INSERT INTO det_release_info (case_urn,acc_status,reason,remarks,userid,department,ministry,registerdate,updated,released,DATE,expected_date,actual_date,is_executed,exec_details,other_reduction,classified)
SELECT t2.case_urn,t2.acc_status,t2.reason,t2.remarks,t2.userid,t2.department,t2.ministry,t2.registerdate,t2.updated,t2.released,t2.date,t2.expected_date,t2.actual_date,t2.is_executed,t2.exec_details,t2.other_reduction,t2.classified FROM cssp_release_info AS t2 LEFT JOIN det_release_info AS t3 ON t3.case_urn=t2.case_urn WHERE t2.acc_status=42 AND t3.registerdate IS NULL
```

But when I run the query, there is an error `Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: Could you post your full sql script? because it seem to work

Comment: @D-Shih I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query so far so good, but I guess you want to use `OUTER JOIN`, you need to let AND `t3.registerdate IS NULL` in on condition, otherwise, mysql engine will let it be `INNER JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO det_release_info 
            (case_urn, 
             acc_status, 
             reason, 
             remarks, 
             userid, 
             department, 
             ministry, 
             registerdate, 
             updated, 
             released, 
             date, 
             expected_date, 
             actual_date, 
             is_executed, 
             exec_details, 
             other_reduction, 
             classified) 
SELECT t2.case_urn, 
       t2.acc_status, 
       t2.reason, 
       t2.remarks, 
       t2.userid, 
       t2.department, 
       t2.ministry, 
       t2.registerdate, 
       t2.updated, 
       t2.released, 
       t2.date, 
       t2.expected_date, 
       t2.actual_date, 
       t2.is_executed, 
       t2.exec_details, 
       t2.other_reduction, 
       t2.classified 
FROM   cssp_release_info AS t2 
WHERE  t2.acc_status = 42 AND t2.case_urn NOT IN (
    SELECT case_urn 
    FROM det_release_info
)
```

Here is a sample for insert into select.

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/67o8rpLfEKBzhnHGQqbafY/0)

**EDIT**

Your query the same as `NOT IN`, so try it.

```
INSERT INTO det_release_info 
            (case_urn, 
             acc_status, 
             reason, 
             remarks, 
             userid, 
             department, 
             ministry, 
             registerdate, 
             updated, 
             released, 
             date, 
             expected_date, 
             actual_date, 
             is_executed, 
             exec_details, 
             other_reduction, 
             classified) 
SELECT t2.case_urn, 
       t2.acc_status, 
       t2.reason, 
       t2.remarks, 
       t2.userid, 
       t2.department, 
       t2.ministry, 
       t2.registerdate, 
       t2.updated, 
       t2.released, 
       t2.date, 
       t2.expected_date, 
       t2.actual_date, 
       t2.is_executed, 
       t2.exec_details, 
       t2.other_reduction, 
       t2.classified 
FROM   cssp_release_info AS t2 
WHERE  t2.acc_status = 42 AND t2.case_urn NOT IN (
    SELECT case_urn 
    FROM det_release_info
)
```

Comment: But I want to filter all records by `t2.acc_status=42` to insert them

Comment: I am not going to insert all the records from cssp_release_info table except the t2.acc_status=42

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari I provide another solution you can try it.

Comment: Is there any trigger in your table?

Comment: Yes there is a trigger

Comment: Thank you so much @D-Shih the issue was with my trigger and i have solved that no issue with query.